# How do I link from Markdown to specific symbol in a code file in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, hyperlink, markdown

VSCode allows for navigating to specific symbol (function, variable, or other) with ⌘+t or ctrl+t or by typing a # symbol in the command window. I'm working on some markdown documentation. VSCode allows for following relative links in markdown; the following would take one to the line 33 in the foo file `./foo.js#L33`. Is there a way to leverage VSCode's linking using a different anchor to navigate directly to a symbol, e.g. `./foo.js#myFunc`?

Comment: i like the same. but link to only the name of the symbol, which is the markdown heading. With this you are enable to restructure the markdown content hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Although this feature would be really useful, there is no way to do this, unfortunately.